# Pandas: fill in a dataframe column with a serie starting at a specifc index

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
    time                   price
0   2019-02-01 00:07:00    0.00234135
1   2019-02-01 00:10:15    0.0023541
2   2019-02-01 00:13:30    0.00235838
3   2019-02-01 01:03:00    0.00236977
4   2019-02-01 01:07:00    0.00237751
```

What I did after was to compute the MACD using the following code: `macd, macd_signal, macd_histogram  = ti.macd(data,10,20,9)`

I would like now to create a new column with the related macd values: `df['macd'] = pd.Series(macd)` however the first 20 values are used to compute the macd, so there is no macd values for the first 20 values.

I should then create a column with the macd values starting at index 20. I tried that: `df.at[18, 'macd'] = pd.Series(macd)` but it did not work I have the following error message :

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: `df.at[18:, 'macd'] = pd.Series(macd)`

Comment: Well done! You can put it as an answer and I will approve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting to `Series` with not defined index is not good idea, because possible not aligment between new `Series` and old index:

```
df.loc[18:, 'macd'] = macd[18:]
```

Solution with `pd.Series`:

```
df.loc[18:, 'macd'] = pd.Series(macd, index=df.index)
```